# select from a list of table names

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I Have a table in sql server 2008 with on column 'TableName' that represents name of specific tables.

```
TableName
----------
Person
Good
Organization
```

I want to iterate through this table and count rows number of each tables.

Comment: Are you trying to get total no of rows in each table?

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta ....Yes,i want to get total no of rows in each table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you table names and no of rows for all the tables.

**Method 1: Using System tables - Gives approximate row count**

```
SELECT p.object_id, t.name, sum(p.rows) from sys.partitions p 
inner join sys.tables t on p.object_id = t.object_id 
group by p.object_id, t.name
order by 1
```

If you are managing your own table

```
SELECT p.object_id, t.name, sum(p.rows) from sys.partitions p 
inner join sys.tables t on p.object_id = t.object_id 
inner join TableName u on u.TableName = t.name
group by p.object_id, t.name
order by 1
```

**Method 2: Using cursor - Exact row count**

```
declare @tbl table(table_name varchar(100), rows bigint)
declare @tblName varchar(100) = ''
DECLARE @cur CURSOR
SET @cur = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
   FOR 
            SELECT TableName FROM YourTable
OPEN @cur

FETCH NEXT FROM @cur
INTO @tblName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  declare @query nvarchar(2000) --Passing parameter into dynamic query
  declare @out bigint =0 --Passing out parameter into dynamic query
  set @query = N'select @out = count(*) from ' + @tblName
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@tblName varchar(100), @out bigint output'
  , @tblName = @tblName, @out = @out OUTPUT;

  INSERT into @tbl (table_name, rows) VALUES(@tblName, @out)

    FETCH NEXT FROM @cur
    INTO @tblName
END
CLOSE @cur
DEALLOCATE @cur

select * from @tbl
```

Comment: Yes, this gives approximate no of rows. If you want to get exact number of rows then you probably have to use cursor to iterate each table.

Comment: OK,How can i use cursors?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume you have a table which contains table names of your database, you can query as.

```
Select count(*) from (select tablename from tablenames);
```